Rails 6.0 + Action Cable : Not receiving "received" data
I'm on Rails 6
Trying to use action cable for the first time and
getting troubles receiving the streams
So far I generated a new channel, and I got this
app/channels/site_generation_progress_messages_channel.rb
class SiteGenerationProgressMessagesChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from "site_generation_progress_messages_channel"
  end

  def unsubscribed
    # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
  end
end

app/javascript/channels/site_generation_progress_messages_channel.js
import consumer from "./consumer"

consumer.subscriptions.create("SiteGenerationProgressMessagesChannel", {
  connected() {
    console.log('Connected to SiteGenerationProgressMessagesChannel');
  },

  disconnected() {
    console.log('DISCONNECTED from SiteGenerationProgressMessagesChannel');
  },

  received(data) {
    console.log('received message');
  }
});

application.js
require("channels")

My controller action
def some_action
  ActionCable.server.broadcast "site_generation_progress_messages_channel", message: "some message"
end

Connection with Websockets seems OK since I'm successfully receiving the very first console log message :
Connected to SiteGenerationProgressMessagesChannel
But after that, nothing happens!
I'm not receiving the message from my controller
I think maybe I forgot a step ?

I don't think we have enough information on your app cycle. How is the controller action w/ the broadcast being triggered?

hi @MicahBrown the controller action is just a simple action leading to a view, nothing more. I thought that putting ActionCable.server.broadcast anywhere in any action would push the message, but maybe that's actually not the case ?

Found the issue, actually my cable.yml config for development environment was not good
had to replace
development:
  adapter: async

by
development:
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://localhost:6379/1

